# how to decode this list element into a single dataframe?

Tags: r

i have the following element which corresponds to a single record. i believe its a list with a dataframe inside.

can you please advise how can i convert it into a single row dataframe so all the information contained gets placed within columns. that way im able to append more records in the future that contain the same structure than this, into a single dataframe

```
a = list(structure(list(ConOrden = 1L, TipoMed = 1L, TipoPrest = 2L, 
    CausaS1 = 0L, CausaS2 = 0L, CausaS3 = 0L, MedPBSUtilizado = NA, 
    RznCausaS31 = 0L, DescRzn31 = NA, RznCausaS32 = 0L, DescRzn32 = NA, 
    CausaS4 = 1L, MedPBSDescartado = "TRAMADOL", RznCausaS41 = 1L, 
    DescRzn41 = "MAL CONTROL DE DOLOR ", RznCausaS42 = 0L, DescRzn42 = NA, 
    RznCausaS43 = 0L, DescRzn43 = NA, RznCausaS44 = 0L, DescRzn44 = NA, 
    CausaS5 = 1L, RznCausaS5 = NA, CausaS6 = NA, DescMedPrinAct = "[ACETAMINOFEN] 325mg/1U ; [CODEINA FOSFATO] 30mg/1U", 
    CodFF = "COLFF001", CodVA = "048", JustNoPBS = "DOLOR SECUDNARIO A ENFERMEDAD ARTERIAL OCLUSIVA ", 
    Dosis = "325", DosisUM = "0168", NoFAdmon = "8", CodFreAdmon = 2L, 
    IndEsp = 10L, CanTrat = "90", DurTrat = 3L, CantTotalF = "270", 
    UFCantTotal = "66", IndRec = "TOMAR UNA CADA 8 HORAS", EstJM = 1L, 
    PrincipiosActivos = list(structure(list(ConOrden = c(1L, 
    1L), CodPriAct = c("00626", "50055"), ConcCant = c("325", 
    "30"), UMedConc = c("0168", "0168"), CantCont = c("1", "1"
    ), UMedCantCont = c("0247", "0247")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), 
    IndicacionesUNIRS = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
a[[1]]
```

It was a list with one element

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `pluck`

```
library(purrr)
pluck(a, 1)
```